# Remove <br /> tag from generated CheckboxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout

I've never been a fan that checkbox lists generate so much markup, but that's besides the point. For various reasons I need to use `RepeatLayout="Flow"` It generates a `<br />` tag between each checkbox.  Outside of using something client side is there a way to not include that with a server side solution?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to implement your own `CheckBoxList` - inherit from the ASP.NET control and then override the method that generates the HTML.  That might be more effort than its worth though.

Comment: Take a look at tag mapping: http://leedumond.com/blog/fixing-asp-net-server-control-rendering-issues-with-tag-mapping/

Comment: I'm a newbie haven't implemented my own `CheckBoxList` before not sure where to start. This is a quick splash page you are right might be more effort than it's worth

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"` to the CheckBoxList tag in your HTML template.